# Pentaho Data Source Wizard

Tags: java, mysql, windows, odbc, pentaho

I'm absolutely newbie in Pentaho and I tried to install this tool.

My problem was when configure the data source. When connect and set the parameters to the DB, connect good and charge all the tables. After, when configure in step 3 the joins for the tables I don't get the columns for this.

In the line command appear the next message when select the tables:

> Couldn't close query: resulset or prepared statements You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION
>   SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT' at line 1

The installation was in Windows 7 x86 with MySQL 5.6, Java JDK 1.7 and Pentaho 5.1
The connect to MySQL was with ODBC 5.3

Thanks'you all!! :D

Comment: Finally it worked after reboot the server ... classic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it by adding ANSI_QUOTES to sql_mode in MySQL. Also, use the newest JDBC/ODBC.

Try "SHOW VARIABLES" in mysql console (or workbench) to be sure that ANSI_QUOTES is avalaible.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading the driver in `PENTAHO\biserver-ce\tomcat\lib` worked for me. They had the 5.1.17 version and the current one is 5.1.34 at the momento of this answer is written.

You may download it from the Oracle [web page](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).